# Flutter app error Exception has occurred. _TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index')

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this exception error when trying to run in flutter ( Exception has occurred. _TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index') error is line serverToken = jsonDecode(data)["key"];

```
 void getFCMServerKey() async {
     final RemoteConfig remoteConfig = await RemoteConfig.instance;
    await remoteConfig.fetch(expiration: const Duration(hours: 5));
    await remoteConfig.activateFetched();
     var data = remoteConfig.getString('FcmServerKey');
     if (data != null) {
       serverToken = jsonDecode(data)["key"];
     }   }
```

Comment: What line is the error?

Comment: sorry valid point!  error is on line serverToken = jsonDecode(data)["key"];

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're writing this `["key"]`

Do this instead:

```
serverToken = jsonDecode(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You got this is error, because when you convert your json data to Dart class `jsonDecode(data)`, you got a `List`. Probably you assumed get a `Map` and tried to access item with `key` parameter and got an error because you can not access items of `List` with string keys you should use `int` index number. Before trying to access item be sure that your data is in format that you want.